# Intel Wifi Periodically Stops Working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, iwlwifi, 22.04

Error:

```
[42740.562956] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[42740.563042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[42740.563047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[42740.563054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode

...

[42740.563724] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[42822.293087] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ae:f6:c7:c3:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[42829.563665] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ae:f6:c7:c3:a8
[42829.568577] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ae:f6:c7:c3:a8 (try 1/3)
[42829.697166] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ae:f6:c7:c3:a8 (try 2/3)
[42829.801205] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ae:f6:c7:c3:a8 (try 3/3)
[42829.875896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not associated and the session protection is over already...
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: f0:77:c3:93:79:3e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.u ip=192.168.1.119 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600111c000-600111ffff
```

`sudo modinfo iwlwifi`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       ...

srcversion:     DD74DCA94629F138F23C44B

...

depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.15.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        47:A1:01:21:37:F5:CD:43:5E:90:FB:53:3A:20:2D:77:C3:0B:6E:13
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      ...
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: But unfortunately you are right. Disabling power saving does not help.

Comment: I'm in the same situation... No idea. Power saving does not solve. I tried following [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=382386)  but no success.